# How to count number of numerical warnings suppressed by Python's filterwarnings?

Tags: python, exception, logging, warnings

The best way to hide Python warnings about division by 0, invalid operations, rounding errors and others is to use

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Instead of suppressing all the warning messages that could appear in the console, is there a way to instead have the *number* (and type) of warnings that were suppressed be tallied as they occur? i.e.,

```
11 warning messages hidden by `filterwarnings('ignore')
```